# How to prevent Print dialogue in Mozilla from CTRL + P

Tags: javascript, printing, mozilla

I have below JavaScript code that gets invoked on pressing CTRL + P on my view. It works on all browsers (tested after updating the userAgent name), but on Mozilla I am not able to block Print Dialogue. What am I doing wrong here?

I am actually trying to add my own logic to print with Ctrl + P (I have multiple i frames on the page and trying to choose which one to print), so after trying for hours, I tried to block it on Mozilla and it turns out that Mozilla still fires the Print dialogue with below code unlike IE 11, Edge, Chrome.

```
$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function (e) {
if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
    var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if(browser.indexOf('firefox') > -1)
   {
       return false;
   }}
}
```

I want to stop the default CTRL + P behavior on Mozilla and run my own script.

This is on MVC web app if at all that matters to anyone.

Comment: have you tried `e.preventDefault()` - you know, to `prevent` the `default` "action" from taking place :p

Comment: Don't try to be too clever. Rather than intercepting Ctrl+P, put a button "Print" or "Print view" in your application and let the user use that.

Comment: @JaromandaX I had tried that, turns out CTRL + P still was firing up the print dialogue. I found out what was the issue that I was stuck in, see below..

Comment: @Bergi I wish I was in control of this feature.. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use this code

```
$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

i.e. always, regardless of browser, preventDefault - I'm surprised you don't need to in other browsers

Comment: It's jQuery, so `return false` from an event handler will essentially do the same for you.

Comment: In that case the original code will work because this code works

Comment: Marking this as answer because this led me to the core of the issue. I had tried return false, but as I mentioned I need to run my own logic after intercepting CTRL+P. Second issue was when you have the developer tools opened and debugger right before that CTRL + P, it will fire up the print dialogue even before the code reaches the line return false or e.preventDefault() and so I used to get two print dialogues, one which is Mozilla's default and second which is my logic. Closing the debugger tools and then trying opens up only my Print dialogue and stops the Mozilla default.

Comment: Guess its a Mozilla bug?